# Assertion with Array in scala

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am trying to assert the condition but getting error.

I have result of  type Either[CaseClass[Array[String]]] with value: Right(CaseClass(Array("value")))

When i do :

```
result should equal(Right(CaseClass(Array("value"))))
```

It gives me:

```
Right(CaseClass([Ljava.lang.String;@6ed4e733) did not equal Right(CaseClass([Ljava.lang.String;@43553bf0))
```

Comment: Try using assertThat(actual, is(whatever)).

Comment: Do you have any reason for using **Arrays** if not, use another, real, collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array` is **not** a true Scala collections and behaves differently, for example

```
List(42) == List(42)    // true
Array(42) == Array(42)  // false
```

where we see array is not compared structurally. Now ScalaTest does provide special handling for `Array` which would indeed compare them structurally

```
Array("") should equal (Array(""))            // pass
```

however it does not work when `Array` is nested in another container

```
case class Foo(a: Array[String])
Foo(Array("")) should equal (Foo(Array("")))  // fail
```

True Scala collections, such as `List`, do not suffer this problem

```
case class Bar(a: List[String])
Bar(List("")) should equal (Bar(List("")))    // pass
```

There is an open issue [Matchers fail to understand Array equality for Arrays wrapped inside a container/collection #491](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/491) to address deep equality checks for `Array` however for now I would suggest switching to `List` instead of `Array`. Another options is to provide your own custom equality designed to handle your specific case.